# Java Heap OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

I am creating a streaming application and when I stream to my client, the client throws an OutOfMemoryError. My Heap is only 6MB big, and I have increased the maximum heap size to 1GB. Is it possible that when I am filling the cache, it fills too fast (for GC?)? Or what could be the problem? Any ideas?

It crashes here (on the first line to be exact):

```
byte[] songData = new byte[length];
ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(packet.getData(), SongDatagram.HEADER_SIZE, length);
dataBuffer.get(songData);
DataPacket dataPacket = new DataPacket(songData);
putIntoCache(dataPacket);
```

This code gets executed a couple thousand times, because I split the song into packets of around 1KB and fill a TreeSet (**the cache**) with these packets ordered by a SequenceNr.

I am analyzing a dump on EMA, but as I said the Heap is only 6 MB (and I understand, even with a memoryleak it would crash when I surpass the maximum heap size at 1 GB).

The error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at utils.networking.SongDatagramBuilder.convertToSongDatagram(SongDatagramBuilder.java:108)
at controllers.networking.streaming.MusicStreamingService.listen(MusicStreamingService.java:142)
at controllers.networking.streaming.MusicStreamingService$$Lambda$59/369920468.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)space
```

Comment: What do you mean by filling the cache ? Please post the complete stacktrace with relevant code

Comment: Your code does not makes sense. You are using packet before creating it.

Comment: Have you checked the actual `length` parameter when the error occurs. If your current heap is 6 MB, but with this single line you try to allocate for example 100 GB, this will cause an OutOfMemoryError with the dump only showing the 6 MB.

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan the cache is basically a TreeSet.

Comment: @Nadir thanks that is a copy paste error. Fixed.

Comment: @Jack no I haven't tried, it might be worth a try!

Comment: @Jack yes, you are right, that is the problem... I was expecting it would never be too big, as it's a constant on server-side. But as I am using a self-made protocol it failed and sent a wrong variable (a big integer) on the data-stream. Then it decoded it wrong and crashed.